# Sending data in key, value pair to api

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, typescript

I have my api method as below:

```
[HttpPost()]
public async Task SaveDataAsync([FromBody] UserData value)
{
     //saving logic here
}
```

Where my UserData is defined as below:

```
public class UserData
{
   public string Conditions { get; set; }
   public DateTime Status { get; set; }
   public Dictionary<string, Guid> userSelections { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, Guid>();   
}
```

How can I send above Dictionary object from my UI.

In my angular UI, user can select multiple data (represented in a table) and call this method to save the data.

I can send some of the data as required, but I am not sure how can I send my object in key, value pair as required above.

So after selection my object (userSelections as represented in my c# object) is as below:

```
0: Name: "Pete", Status: "open", id="af9f9937-f51a-4fd8-b29c-f9ef899684c9"
1: Name: "Smith", Status: "closed", id="vfdf9337-f51s-wfd8-b49-f5ef799h84c9"
2: Name: "Ang", Status: "open", id="334dd33-d3e3-cxc333-e3c-ccdc3cd32"
```

How can I create key value pair of name and id from above and send it to my api

Below is my call to the api from angular

```
//this holds above data
 const userSelectedData = []; 

 const userData = {
        'name': userName,
        'conditions': conditions,
        'userSelections': userSelectedData       
      };

      this.service.save(userData)
        .subscribe(
          (res) => {            
            //saved         
          });         
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the `userSelectedData` structure/example in typescript.

Comment: I am looping through selected data of ngFor and populating the userSelectedData. The json example I gave above is the one use selects

Answer (score 0):

Since I have only basic knowledge of C#, I assume that the service accepts a JSON in the given format.

```
{
  'Conditions': '',
  'Status': '',
  'userSelections': {
    'name': 'id'
  }
}
```

To get `userSelections` in correct format as the service accepts, you can map the array records to the specified structure.

```
let obj = {};
(userSelectedData || []).forEach(d => {
  obj[d.Name] = d.id;
});

const userData = {
  'name': userName,
  'conditions': conditions,
  'userSelections': obj       
};
```

Comment: when I am creating using obj[d.Name] = d.id. Its creating as: myData:"d3875a18-608f-4216-abe8-326aa95f154a" . Cant I have name "myData" in quotes

Comment: Both are same only, whether you get in quotes or without. However, you will get in quotes if you stringify `userData` using `JSON.stringify(userData)`